# Is the bulk grounded in small AC signal analysis?

Tags: mosfet, small-signal, bulk-capacitor

This the circuit. The bulk is connected to ground in DC.

Is the bulk grounded in small AC signal analysis (V<sub>b</sub> = 0)?

[image]

[image]

How about for PMOS? When the bulk of PMOS is connected to VDD, is the bulk grounded in small AC signal analysis (V<sub>b</sub> = 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's connected to ground/VDD in the original schematic, then it's grounded in an AC analysis because we assume ground/VDD to be a DC constant voltage.

Small-signal analysis is about slopes, and slope of a fixed DC voltage is 0.

Comment: When \$V_{bs}\$ = 0, is \$C_{bs}\$ shorted so it can omitted in small signal analysis?

Comment: @kile only if ignore RS, i.e. you assume it's very small.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does \$C_{bs}\$ matter  when bulk and source are both grounded? In my opinion \$C_{bs}\$ are shorted, so it won't have any effect on the ac circuit

Comment: It'll probably not do anything as you say, but under the assumption that \$R_s\$ is small, which usually is. If that were big, then the bottom side of \$C_{bs}\$ cannot be assumed to be 0.